# Alocação de memoria de um serviço

Tags: c#

Estou com um problema, preciso verificar a quantidade de memória que um serviço especifico está alocando.

Existe algo em C# que faça isso? Alguma classe ou método?

Pois todas que vi, trazem a informação geral de consumo do PC.

Comment: É possível mas depende de como está isso, você não deu nenhum detalhe. Certamente não há algo mágico que você coloque e ele adivinhe a quantidade de memória usada de algo não especificado. Se você não sabe o que você quer descobrir, você vai descobrir nada. Então fale pra gente o que você quer saber. Talvez você não precise disto de fato.

Comment: Deixa eu detalhar então. Meu sistema tem um serviço CacheService.exe, ele vai alocando memória conforme vai sendo utilizado eu gostaria de criar um JOB em c# para ir verificando  a quantidade de memória que ele está consumindo.

Answer (score 1):

Para saber informações sobre um serviço basta pegar o processo associado a esse serviço e avaliar suas propriedades:

```
// Pega todos os serviços ativos com o nome NomedoServiço.exe e faz uma inspeção superficial em suas propriedades
foreach(var Processo  in  Process.GetProcessesByName("NomedoServiço.exe")){

    Console.WriteLine($"{Processo}-{Processo.Id}");
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------");

    Console.WriteLine($"  Uso de memória física  : {Processo.WorkingSet64}");              
    Console.WriteLine($"  Tempo de uso da CPU    : {Processo.TotalProcessorTime}");
    Console.WriteLine($"  Memória paginada       : {Processo.PagedMemorySize64}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Felipe Rosa
Você está querendo saber quanto de memória a sua aplicação utiliza, é isto que entendi.
Bom, encontrei algumas publicações que poderão auxiliá-lo, porém tem que pesquisar sobre sistemas operacionais, isso o ajudará, vamos lá, então:

O que encontrei e que está como entendi da sua questão é Monitorando o consumo de memória e tempo de execução

Read more: http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3077/monitorando-o-consumo-de-memoria-e-tempo-de-execucao.aspx

Este segundo está em inglês é mais abrangente mas acredito estar ligado ao que você precisa 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18727/Customized-Task-Manager-in-NET-using-C-and-Windows
Acredito que com estes dois modelos você conseguirá atingir o seu objetivo.

att

LMV